# Draw themed border of a TEdit

Tags: delphi

I want to draw the themed border of a TEdit in a Paintbox. The code must be functional under Windows Vista and 7. I have tried the following. It works only under Windows XP.

```
var
  Details: TThemedElementDetails;   //uses Themes
begin
  if ThemeServices.ThemesEnabled then
  begin
    Details := ThemeServices.GetElementDetails(teEditRoot);
    ThemeServices.DrawElement(PaintBox1.Canvas.Handle, Details, PaintBox1.ClientRect);
  end;
end;
```

Under Windows XP all ist OK. But under Windows Vista and 7 the border is painted in dark gray. All 4 sides in the same color. But a TEdit under Vista looks different: The top border has a dark gray. The right border a medium gray. The left and bottom borders have a light gray. I hope you understand the difference. How to paint it in the right way? Thanks!

Comment: Under http://www.delphipraxis.net/153127-theme-rahmen-vom-tedit-zeichnen.html you can find a German thread regarding this issue. However no solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
R := Rect(15, 15, 80, 30);
DrawThemeBackground(ThemeServices.Theme[teEdit], PaintBox1.Canvas.Handle, EP_EDITBORDER_NOSCROLL, ETS_NORMAL, R, @R);
/// DrawThemeBackground(ThemeServices.Theme[teEdit], PaintBox1.Canvas.Handle, EP_EDITTEXT, ETS_NORMAL, R, @R); <<< XP Behaviour
```

If you want your code to run in XP you should make that conditional, as on WinXP you should use the 2nd one.